# Embedded Youtube on iPad has the lowest quality

Tags: ios, ipad, youtube, youtube-api

I did try with a partial solution that I found here in another question that was very similar but nothing happened, the Youtube embedded player in iPad is awful, the video that I get looks like 240p. The curious thing is that in the iPhone works perfect, the quality is way superior.

Answer (score 0):

I found a little hack here and I finally manage to implement into my project:

[This is the link with the answer that I found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22547853/embedded-youtube-how-to-get-high-quality-on-ios-7-ipad)

To begin that iPad needs a "width" parameter to output the video as it should be, otherwise it will do it with the lowest resolution (150 x 300):

https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/AudioandVideoTagBasics/AudioandVideoTagBasics.html

So as in the answer of the user Thayne says we must put the maximun resolution of the video and then adjust it as he did. The only one problem is that the controls look very small:

At the end my code looked like this (making it responsive)

```
div.field-content iframe,div.field-content object,div.field-content embed {position: absolute;top: 0;left: 0;width: 1280px !important;height: 720px !important;-webkit-transform-origin: left top;-webkit-transform: scale(0.4);}



#quicktabs-english_tabs,  #quicktabs-french_tabs, #quicktabs-spanish_tabs, #quicktabs-portuguese_tabs, #quicktabs-russian_tabs, #quicktabs-arabic_tabs, #quicktabs-chinese_tabs{width: 520px !important;}
```